# Create text remarks for students based on their scores

Tags: java, sql

I have a database table that keeps records of students scores and remarks based on their performance:

```
| NAME   | SCORE | REMARKS | 
+--------+-------+---------+
| james  | 150.0 |         | 
| jimmy  | 90.0  |         | 
| josh   | 200.0 |         |
```

I want to update the "remarks" column based on the scores of the student, such that if student score is less than 100, remarks text will be "Fail", from 100 to 160: "average pass" and from 161 to 250 "Pass".

I wrote this code:

```
String student_score, remark;
double type;
try {
    String sql = "select SCORE from class";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    student_score = rs.getString("SCORE");
    type = Double.parseDouble(student_score);
    while (rs.next()) {
        if (type >= 1 && type <= 100) {
            remark = "fail";
            String sql1 = "update class set Remarks='" + remark + "'" + " WHERE SCORE='" + type + "'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            pst.execute();
        } else if (type >= 101 && type <= 160) {
            remark = "average pass";
            String sql1 = "update class1 set Remarks='" + remark + "'" + " WHERE SCORE='" + type + "'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            pst.execute();
        } else if (type >= 161 && type <= 250) {
            remark = "pass";
            String sql1 = "update class set Reemarks='" + remark + "'" + " WHERE SCORE='" + type + "'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            pst.execute();
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
```

But with this, I only get the first row filled, the rest remains empty:

```
| NAME  | SCORE | REMARKS    | 
+-------+-------+------------+
| james | 150.0 |average pass| 
| jimmy | 90.0  |            | 
| josh  |200.0  |            |
```

Comment: There’s no need to select any rows. Just make update statements that are run for rows with the conditions given. That will work a lot better. As for the problem: see where you set `type` and learn how to use a debugger, it will help a lot.

Comment: You also have a typo, it seems that you are dealing with two distinct target tables : `class` and `class1` .

Comment: Why is "score" named `type` in the code? Extract repeated code outside the if/else blocks, make sure there are no typos ("class1", "Reemarks", etc.). Also, it's a strange idea to use "SCORE" in the where clause for setting, this will result in updating the same record several times for students with the same score.

Answer (score 1):

move

```
student_score = rs.getString("SCORE");
type = Double.parseDouble(student_score);
```

to `while` loop

```
while (rs.next()) {
 student_score = rs.getString("SCORE");
 type = Double.parseDouble(student_score); 
        ...
}
```

Comment: many thanks @kryger, Aarif Aslam, Sami Kuhmonen,Berger...... your suggestions all hepled. and very sorry for the typo errors. they were made when i was posting the question... its class and Remarks. Thanks again...you all have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to satisfy your requirement will be to do it all directly in SQL:

```
String sql1 = "update class set Remarks='fail' WHERE SCORE BETWEEN 1 AND 100";
String sql2 = "update class set Remarks='average pass' WHERE SCORE BETWEEN 101 AND 160";
String sql3 = "update class set Remarks='pass' WHERE SCORE BETWEEN 161 AND 250";

// execute the queries
```

It's not the "best practice" to do it this way, but it's equivalent to your solution while more compact and easier to refactor in the future.